# jQuery: Return multiple dynamic variables from a FOR LOOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, for-loop

I want to count all elements with a class of `.step` then make a `for` loop and return variables that select each of the corresponding element. Here's my code:

```
var steps = $('.step').length;
var i = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    return var step + i = $('.step' + i);
}
```

EDIT: To make myself clear, instead of doing it like this:

```
var step1 = $('.step1.');
var step2 = $('.step2.');
// etc..
```

I want to use a `for` loop to get each element with a class of `.step` and return each one in a different variable, like so: `step1`, `step2`, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: The `return` statement immediately exits the function it appears in, returning *one* value or object, so trying to use it in a loop like that makes no sense.

Comment: Why wouldn't this just be `$('.step')`? It's not actually clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: A better way is to create an array with size of steps and then save the elements in the array

Comment: why do you not just return $(".step");

Comment: provide a sample of the elements you want to select.

Comment: This seems completely pointless. The resulting array would be the same as just selecting `$('.step')` to start with. If you want to access them by index, use `eq()`, like this `$('.step').eq(0)`

Comment: Pretty much *any* time you find yourself creating `something1`, `something2`, `something3`, etc., variables you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the data in an array, you can try something like this:

```js
var data = $(".step").map(function(s, index) {
  return $(".step" + (s + 1));
});
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step step1">1</div>
<div class="step step2">2</div>
<div class="step step3">3</div>
<div class="step step4">4</div>
<div class="step step5">5</div>
<div class="step step6">6</div>
```

But I would rather suggest you to store data in an object. This would be easier to access.

```js
var obj = {};
$(".step").each(function(i, el) {
  var _i = i + 1;
  obj["step" + _i] = $(".step" + _i);
});

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step step1">1</div>
<div class="step step2">2</div>
<div class="step step3">3</div>
<div class="step step4">4</div>
<div class="step step5">5</div>
<div class="step step6">6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess for what you want is this:

```
var result = [];
$('.step').each(function(i) {
  result.push( $('.step' + i) );
});
return result;
```

That will return an array of [all the `.step1` elements, all the `.step2` elements, ...]